# I am trying to create a properties page in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I need some help creating a properties page in Android.

I have created an Activity and have a TableLayout with a title, 5 properties that include a Spinner to select a property class and a EditText that the user can type into, followed by a couple of buttons reading Accept and Cancel.

I am launching the activity by creating a new Intent with that class and using a StartActivityForResult, where I need to Bundle all of the properties back to my main activity.  I have an OnActivityResult defined in the main class.  I am having difficulty in the properties page on how to return the activity result from the button callback and how to package and return the Bundle.  Any not so simple examples would be appreciated.

Comment: you may want to add something about StartActivtyForResult in the title of this ??? Question doesn't seem to have to do much todo with a properties page.

Answer (score 1):

on the Activity that is returning the result you would do something like this

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.putExtra("value_a", someValue);
 i.putExtra("value_b", anothervalue);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
 finish();
```

then in the activity that is waiting for the result you would do something like this

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) // 0 would be whatever id you gave this when you started the activity for result
      {
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          String property_a = extras.getString("value_a"); 
          String property_b = extras.getString("value_b");
          // ... whatever else you need to with the results, maybe they are not strings...??
      }

    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing.  I had a little issue packaging the data into the Bundle but once resolved everything looks good.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Preference Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) to store yours application settings

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for but it will work nicely for the top level preferences dialog.  My properties page will have to use dropdown lists and text fields, basically to have the user select up to 5 different gasses and their molar concentrations.